# Match all lines matching a string in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a string which I need to find in all XML files. I am using notepad ++.

**String:**

```
<PARA APPLIC="ST2, LT5"><XREFEXT DATAREF="LRCS000005678" PARTTYPE="FIGURE" XIDTYPE="GRAPHIC"/></PARA>
```

I need to find all files which contain 'ST2' in  PARA APPLIC and PARA element should be followed by XREFXT element with XIDTYPE="GRAPHIC"

**Example:**

```
<PARA APPLIC="XXX,"ST2","XXX"> followed by <XREFXT DATAREF="XXXXXXXXXXX" PARTTYPE="FIGURE" XIDTYPE="GRAPHIC"/></PARA>
```

'X' represents wild character.

ST2 can be anywhere places in the APPLIC
example:

- APPLIC="ABC, "ST2", "RT4"
- APPLIC="ST2", "GHT", "HYT"
- APPLIC="HYT", "ST2"

Comment: XML and regex are not good fiends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: Any suggestion on a parser?

Comment: A simple search for XML parser points to http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php for example.

Comment: @Toto I have no problems with Notepad++ and using regex on XML. You just need proper escaping and understanding of regex.

Comment: @LPChip:You can use regex on XML for simple cases only, not complex ones. consider `<tag1 attr1="></tag1>"  attr2="<tag2>"><tag2>blah</tag2></tag1>`.

Comment: @Toto your example is indeed harder to construct, but OP's example is not. You say that XML is not gonna work well, but in OP's case it can be. My point was more that if it can work, don't suggest that it might not.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Notepad++ Regular Expression of the following would get you the lines you are looking for.  I'm not sure what you are planning to do with this or how large these files are, but I'd probably look to use something like Windows PowerShell instead so that you can automatically parse these lines into a new file or to grab the exact filenames and to dump those into a new XML or CSV file by themselves.

```
^.*(ST2).*(XREFEXT DATAREF=")
```

Comment: Why are you using groups? This regex doesn't work, it doesn't match `XIDTYPE="GRAPHIC"` that is requested, It matches `XREFEXT` evan if it is not inside `PARA` tag. And some more errors...

Comment: I missed the 2nd match of XIDType="GRAPHIC" when first looking at this.  I'll have to spend some more time on it with that in mind.